# problem about opening the code in the browser

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio, github

I am using `ASP.NET MVC5` for designing a web application, I started coding and in the middle of the process, I pushed my code into GitHub. The problem is that after doing this I am not able to view my work on the browser anymore(the "View in browser" item does not appear anymore on the list). How can I show my web application on the browser and solve this problem?

I added images for more understanding.

[image: Solution explorer]

[image: Options]

Comment: When u run the app, what are you seeing??... you need to run the app. and navigate to that page. "View in Browser" is not how to see a page in asp.net mvc. (looks like you are coming from a webforms background... lols)

Answer (score 0):

Run the app, then go to /home/index

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happened.

1. Try restarting visual Studio

If that does not work  try to install it explicitly from

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.view-in-browser